# Difficulty solving problem regarding 2 parallel vectors

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I have been asked to solve the following question, and I am not sure where to begin with it :

Given two vectors $a$ and $b$ , where the magnitude of $b$ is double the
magnitude of $a$ and the angle between the two vectors is $60°$, we may
define two further vectors: $c = a − 2b$ and $d =14a − 2b$ .

Show that the vectors c and d are perpendicular to each other.

I am aware that $$a\cdot b = \vert a\vert\cdot \vert b\vert\cdot cos $$

However im not sure how to apply it in this question.

Any help in solving this question and the methodology to solve it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$c\cdot d=(a-2b)\cdot (14a-2b)=14|a|^2-30a\cdot b+4|b|^2$$

Use that

$$|b|=2|a| \quad (1)$$
and then

$$a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos 60º \rightarrow a\cdot b=2|a|^2\cdot1/2=|a|^2 \quad (2)$$

Remember that $c \perp d \Leftrightarrow c \cdot d=0$.

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get:

$$c\cdot d=14|a|^2-30a\cdot b+4|b|^2=14|a|^2-30|a|^2+4\cdot 4|a|^2=0$$

Comment: how does 
$$ a* 14a = 14|a|^2$$
 not $$a* 14a = 14a^2$$

Comment: Remember that $a$ is a vector, then $a\cdot a=|a|^2$. For example if $a=(x,y)$ then $(x,y)\cdot (x,y)=x.x+y.y=x^2+y^2=|(x,y)|^2$. is that clear?

Comment: I have always thought that $$|a|= \sqrt {a{_x}^2+a{_y}^2} $$

therefore
$$|a|^2= a{_x}^2+a{_y}^2 $$

so how does 
$$a{_x}^2+a{_y}^2 = a*a$$

Comment: You are missing the definition of Dot Product. If $u=(u_x,u_y)$ and $v=(v_x,v_y)$ then $$u\cdot v=u_x.v_x+u_y.v_y $$. Now make $u=v=a=(a_x,a_y)$ and conclude that $$a\cdot a=(a_x)^2+(a_y)^2=|a|^2$$.

Comment: Thankyou for this, I am still not sure how to get to the solution from here.

Comment: I finished the solution but I recommend you take a close look in the theory of Dot Product. I mean, definition and properties.